# C# - Remove un-wanted characters

Tags: c#

I made a proxy scraper but I have faced one problem:

```
Regex rgx = new Regex(@"[a-zA-Z<>/]");
        WebClient wc = new WebClient();
        foreach(string s in urls)
            try
            {
                string url = wc.DownloadString(s);
                foreach(string reg in regex) // Regex is a list that read regex from text file
                {
                    MatchCollection mc = Regex.Matches(url, reg);
                    foreach (Match m in mc)
                    {
                        Proxies.Add(m.ToString());
                    }
                }
            }
            catch
            {

            }
        Proxies = Proxies.Distinct().ToList(); // Remove duplicate lines
```

Regex I use:

```
\d{1,4}[.]\d{1,4}[.]\d{1,4}[.]\d{1,4}[:0-9]+
\d{1,8}[.]\d{1,8}[.]\d{1,8}\d{1,8}[.]\d{1,8}<\/td><td>[0-9]+
```

because I don't know how to make regex that will work on every website, I had to make a text file so the user can make his own regex.

the problem with the second regex is that it will scrape like this:

```
1.1.1.1</td><td>8080
```

I want it to replace un-wanted characters: "<>/abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz" with ":"

Comment: I would recommend to not using regex for cleaning HTML. HTML isn't a regular language and so we always keep these kind of problems.

Comment: Instead of removing characters from the entire scraped webpage, focus on reading the targeted html sections. It would be much easier. Let the user mention the section ids or names etc. for targeting